# JSON.parse gives unexpected token error with correct JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I know this question appeared already some times but the answers did not hep me.
I got a json string like this:

```
var jsonData = {
"target1": [
{"x":"222",
"y":"333",
"WPtext":"go right"},
{"x":"444",
"y":"444",
"WPtext":"go left"}
],
"target2": [
 {"x":"111",
 "y":"123",
"WPtext":"turn left"}
]
};

var waypoints = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

The last statement throws the error: unexpected token o
I'm not able to figure out whats wrong here, any help is appreciated,
thank you,

Chris

Comment: `jsonData` is already an object so why you want to parse it?

Comment: Your JSON is already parsed

Comment: `typeof jsonData` is already `object`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for the quick reply - 
meanwhile I figured it out also: it should be:
    var jsonData = '{[ .....  ]}'
Ths single quotes around the whole string was missing.

Comment: If you already have the object, why would you make it into the string and then parse it back into the object it already was?